# Drop a Tobit E-mail (eml) on a c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, eml

I have a question about dropping e-mails (eml files) on a wpf application.
My problem is that my application stores the eml file, but if I open it, my Tobit E-mail client shows me an empty mail. Dropping on desktop and open it works perfect. Just as other files like images or text files are working too.

Thank you for every help.

Here is my code:

```
private void listViewDocumentsSA_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)...

        string[] format = e.Data.GetFormats();

        System.Windows.DataObject obj = (System.Windows.DataObject)e.Data;

        Object item = (object)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));            

        try
        {

            string[] fileNames = null;
            string dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dir"];

            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            string filename = "";


            if (e.Data is System.Windows.DataObject && ((System.Windows.DataObject)e.Data).ContainsFileDropList())
            {
                foreach (string filePath in ((System.Windows.DataObject)e.Data).GetFileDropList())
                {
                    filename = dir + "test" + "$" + System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "$" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    filename = filename.Replace("\\\\", "\\");

                    File.Copy(filePath, filename, false);
                }

            }


            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
            {

                Stream theStream = (Stream)e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
                byte[] fileGroupDescriptor = new byte[512];
                theStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptor, 0, 512);

                StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 76; fileGroupDescriptor[i] != 0; i++)
                {
                    fileName.Append(Convert.ToChar(fileGroupDescriptor[i]));
                }
                theStream.Close();

                string path = dir + "test" + "$" + System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "$";
                path = path.Replace("\\\\", "\\");

                string theFile = path + fileName.ToString();


                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileContents", false))
                {


                    string[] formats = e.Data.GetFormats();

                    MemoryStream ms = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW") as MemoryStream;

                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[ms.Length];

                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);


                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(theFile, FileMode.Create);
                    fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, (int)fileBytes.Length);

                    fs.Close();
                }
                else
                    throw new System.Exception("...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```